# Sound stopped working on Ubuntu 16.x

Tags: 14.04, sound

I m using Linux Ubuntu 16.x version. Sound stopped working recently. I assume this is a software problem. 
Can some one suggest me how to overcome this?

Comment: From the about page of the sound tag: Please provide [AlsaInfo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo) and a verbose [PulseAudio log](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log) if your have an issue related to ALSA, PulseAudio or both. See [Debugging Sound Problems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems) and [Sound troubleshooting procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 16.04 you will see a little speaker at the very top of your desktop click on that speaker. Here are a few things to look for

1. Check to see if your sound maybe muted if it is just on tick that box
2. Check the sound output make sure your audio device is present
3. While in the sound settings check the sound level to make sure it's at least mid way